# Convergence rate - Convex optimization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

What is the best known algorithm in terms of convergence rate for unconstrained convex optimization and under what assumptions?

$\min_{x} f(x)$

where $f(x)$ is a given twice differentiable convex function

Comment: The performance of an optimization algorithm depends on, among other things, the regularity of $f$.

Comment: OK, edited my question

Comment: In some cases method A may outperform method B, however with method B it is possible to rewrite the objective function and add a constraint so that it greatly outperforms method A. This type of example can be seen in quadratic programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply specifying that a function is twice differentiable is not enough to guarantee a complexity rate.

The best theoretical treatment of second-order methods---that is, methods that exploit both first- and second-derivative information---is probably by Yurii Nesterov and Arkadii Nemirovskii. Their work requires an assumption of *self-concordance*, which in the scalar case is
$$|f'''(x)|\leq \alpha (f''(x))^{3/2} \quad \forall x$$
for some fixed constant $\alpha>0$.

For methods that exploit only first-derivative information, a good resource is... Nesterov once again. There too, you need additional information about $f$, such as Lipschitz continuity of the gradient. Again, in the scalar case, this looks like
$$|f'(x)-f'(y)| \leq L |x-y|$$
If you also have *strong convexity* you can get even better performance bounds.

Your best bet to learn more here is Google. The search terms I'd use for the first case is "self-concordant Newton's method", and for the second, "accelerated first-order methods." The general point here is this: to answer the question of complexity, you need two things: the set of calculations you are allowed to perform on the function (e.g., how many derivatives), and a *regularity condition* of some sort that ensures that those function values don't change too fast.